# Instagram API How do you get the comments a user has made?

Tags: api, rest, instagram

Hey guys I've been playing with the instagram api quite a bit, and ran into a road block. It is very easy to get the comments on a users images and etcetra, but I cannot for the life of my figure out how to find the comments that a user has made on others' pictures and videos. Is this tucked into the API somewhere hidden? I would expect it to be something like

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/###/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

or something but no bueno, anyone know how to do it? Looks like the only way is to know the media id of what has been commented on beforehand, but there's no place to figure that out either. So if user /v1/users/self made a comment on some random image, there is no way to figure it out from the API what they have actually commented on to my knowledge?

Something else that's a bummer is that this seems like it is the exact same for things that the user likes as well??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe you are right, you need to know the media-id in order to get the comments on that specific media.

There is a way to [get all the media that the authenticated user has LIKED](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked), so perhaps accessing comments like this is something that's coming. Maybe send @InstagramHelp a tweet (I have no idea if that is still monitored)

Comment: That Twitter account is suspended